# How to stop execution when a return statement is encountered in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a function with multiple return statements. I want to stop execution of my program (during debugging) when a return statement is about to be executed within this function.

One way to do this is add break points at all the return statements, but is there another way?

Comment: I would say the best method is to use a breakpoint. That is what they are for.

Comment: Well there are tens of return statements in a single function, I actually wanted to avoid adding break points to all of them. Or if there is a simple way of adding break points to all of them, I'm interested in that too.

Comment: You could temporarily replace return with assert(false); return but that will be different behavior.

Comment: There is also this: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak) maybe search and replace return with `DebugBreak(); return`

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the closing brace at the end of the function.  This only works in Debug builds.

Comment: I can use the DebubgBreak() option but then I have to recompile the code. I may not know to which function I have to add this before hand, so I would prefer to do it without editing the code.

Comment: @PaulSanders, I did not try that, thank you for the suggestion. Would it stop the execution before function exits or at the return statement?

Comment: Before the function exits.

Comment: if you have so many return statements in 1 function that setting breakpoints to all of them is a chore, then maybe it's time to refactor your function.

Comment: Putting a breakpoint on each return is often the best solution anyway as you know which return you hit (and remove irrelevant breakpoints). Otherwise, you can use **step out** command.

Comment: _"Well there are tens of return statements in a single function"_ It's too big! Refactor it first. No wonder you can't find the bug in it ;)

Comment: I'm dealing with legacy code, can't even change a single line without answering multiple questions

Comment: If you can't change the code, then set a breakpoint on every return.

Comment: @pasha: The take-away message here is that it would be a lot of work for Microsoft to add such a feature to Visual Studio, and yet it would be be rather worthless feature as almost no user would need that feature. Almost nobody has that many returns. The chief exception would be in generated code, and then you'd tackle it in the generator, not the debugger.

Comment: ***I'm dealing with legacy code, can't even change a single line without answering multiple questions*** I assume there is some type of software version control being used. Can you make the change while you debug and revert the change at some point after or not checkin the change to your fellow workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can do to a break-on-any-return is a step-out (shift+f11) from an existing breakpoint in the function. This won't let you inspect arguments to the return expression but it will let you inspect the value that is actually returned to the calling function. If you need to break from a running program then you are stuck needing to add breakpoints (either using the IDE or by calling DebugBreak() (or _CrtDbgBreak() if you want them to disappear from release builds).

Comment: I was really hoping these aren't my only options.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are there will be a single return generated in assembler. If you open up the assemble window and find the function exit, you should be able to stick a break point there.

Comment: But will it let me know, out of multiple return statements, which one got executed?

Comment: Debugger is not that smart